# ElasticSearch Windows Install Failing

Tags: java, windows, elasticsearch

I am trying to get started with ElasticSearch, and running into a roadblock.
Attempting to use the tutorial from: joelabrahamsson.com/elasticsearch-101/ 
Running Windows 7 32 bit, and have downloaded:
ElasticSearch-5.2.2
Kibana-5.2.1
Logstash-5.2.2
JDK1.8.0_121
JRE1.8.0_121

I have set the JAVA environments for BOTH the JDK and JRE based on the Atlassian tutorial https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver071/installing-java-802592166.html and these are NOT set to the bin directory for either one.

Next I am launching Kibana and browsing to localhost:5601 and it delivers the GUI, but complains about:
1 - Status Red
2 - ui settings ElasticSearch plugin is red "Elasticsearch plugin is red"
3 - plugin:elasticsearch@5.2.1 "Unable to connect to Elasticsearch at localhost:9200."

So I tried the installer 
...but with the elasticsearch-service.bat install
...we get the following error feedback in the command line:
Installing service: "elasticsearch-service-x86"
Using JAVA_HOME (32-bit): "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121"
Failed installing 'elasticsearch-service-x86' service'

Any advice?

thanks!

Comment: can you paste you startup log file?

Comment: [2017-03-22 14:34:29] [info]  [ 2052] Commons Daemon procrun (1.0.15.0 32-bit) started
[2017-03-22 14:34:29] [info]  [ 2052] Service elasticsearch-service-x86 name Elasticsearch 5.2.2 (elasticsearch-service-x86)
[2017-03-22 14:34:29] [error] [ 2052] The specified service already exists.

Comment: [2017-03-22 14:34:29] [error] [ 2052] Failed installing 'elasticsearch-service-x86' service
[2017-03-22 14:34:29] [error] [ 2052] The specified service already exists.
[2017-03-22 14:34:29] [error] [ 2052] Commons Daemon procrun failed with exit value: 8 (Failed to install service)
[2017-03-22 14:34:29] [error] [ 2052] The specified service already exists.

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0):

the logs says you already have a service installed by the same name. You can check that service in service manager and you can remove it.

1) click run and search for `'services.msc'` and click.

2) From the list of services search for the service named '`elasticsearch-service-x86`', select it and right click and select uninstall. Here you can also control already installed service to start, stop.

If you wish to keep this service, you can change the name of the service you are trying to install in the following file.

`/bin/elasticsearch-service.bat` at line 72 or 66 depending your machine.

But again elastic publish port will be occupied (`9200 and 9300` for transport client) so you will again get this error and you can change these ports in `elasticsearch.yml` file.

Thanks

Comment: Right-clicking "Elasticsearch 5.2.1 (elasticsearch-service-86)" displays:
  Start
  Stop
  Pause
  Resume
  Restart
  All Tasks
     Start
     Stop
     Pause
     Resume
     Restart
  Refresh
  Properties
  Help

Not sure how to proceed...

Comment: yeah, you can start, stop .... the service already installed. I am not sure what you want to do with this service which is already installed on your machine, but if you are looking to delete this already installed service just issue this command from command prompt "sc delete ServiceName".

Comment: Thanks - we made partial progress...I got the Elasticsearch service uninstalled through the commandline and have re-installed.

Comment: But now we have the following error when trying to start Elasticsearch:
The Elasticsearch 5.2.1 (elasticsearch-service-x86) service on local Computer started and then stopped. Some services may stop automatically if they are not in use by other services or programs.

Comment: ...and the Elasticsearch log reads:

2017-03-30 22:55:03 Commons Daemon procrun stdout initialized
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Initial heap size set to a larger value than the maximum heap size

So I have tried to adjust the Java value, now set at 1024mb, but no improvement.

Any advice? Thank you so much!

Comment: how are you handling heap_size on windows. did you defined any environment variables or anything, please also share your elasticsearch.yml file

Comment: sorry for the delay...as for the elasticsearch.yml file it looks like every line is commented out

# ======================== Elasticsearch Configuration =========================
#
# NOTE: Elasticsearch comes with reasonable defaults for most settings.
#       Before you set out to tweak and tune the configuration, make sure you
#       understand what are you trying to accomplish and the consequences.
#
# The primary way of configuring a node is via this file. This template lists
# the most important settings you may want to configure for a production cluster.

Comment: # Please consult the documentation for further information on configuration options:
# https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/index.html
#
# ---------------------------------- Cluster -----------------------------------
#
# Use a descriptive name for your cluster:
#
#cluster.name: my-application
# ------------------------------------ Node ------------------------------------
#
# Use a descriptive name for the node:
#
#node.name: node-1
#
# Add custom attributes to the node:
#
#node.attr.rack: r1

Comment: # ----------------------------------- Paths ---------
#
# Path to directory where to store the data (separate multiple locations by comma):
#
#path.data: /path/to/data
#
# Path to log files:
#
#path.logs: /path/to/logs
# ----------------------------------- Memory --------------------
#
# Lock the memory on startup:
#
#bootstrap.memory_lock: true
#
# Make sure that the heap size is set to about half the memory available
# on the system and that the owner of the process is allowed to use this
# limit.
#
# Elasticsearch performs poorly when the system is swapping the memory.

Comment: # ---------------------------------- Network -----------------------------------
#
# Set the bind address to a specific IP (IPv4 or IPv6):
#
#network.host: 192.168.0.1
#
# Set a custom port for HTTP:
#
#http.port: 9200
#
# For more information, consult the network module documentation.

Comment: # --------------------------------- Discovery ----------------------------------
#
# Pass an initial list of hosts to perform discovery when new node is started:
# The default list of hosts is ["127.0.0.1", "[::1]"]
#
#discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["host1", "host2"]
#
# Prevent the "split brain" by configuring the majority of nodes (total number of master-eligible nodes / 2 + 1):
#
#discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 3
#
# For more information, consult the zen discovery module documentation.

Comment: # ---------------------------------- Gateway -----------------------------------
#
# Block initial recovery after a full cluster restart until N nodes are started:
#
#gateway.recover_after_nodes: 3
#
# For more information, consult the gateway module documentation.
#
# ---------------------------------- Various -----------------------------------
#
# Require explicit names when deleting indices:
#
#action.destructive_requires_name: true

Comment: just now learning about Heap Sizes, so I cannot say there is a real strategy in place. Based on your question I found an article https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/heap-sizing.html . This machine currently has 2 gigs of RAM, though I could upgrade to max it out at 8 gigs. any thoughts here? This is totally new to me. - thank you so much